# ASPNET MVC: autocomplete field but need to save the ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Person DB table that has a `surname`, `name`, and `IdCity` fields.

In the View, I've implemented an autocomplete field to let the user digit the city.

How should I design the ViewModel for handling the `IdCity` and how can I pass it to the controller? It is a string but I need to pass the id and eventually insert it in the DB if it does not exist there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receive the city name in your view action, then look if a city exists for this name. If it does, use its ID. If it doesn't create a new one, and use that ID:

```
public ActionResult Update(PersonModel model)
{
    var city = _cityRepository.GetCityByName(model.CityName);
    if (city == null) _cityRepository.Add(city);

    // At this point city.Id contains your city Id
    var person = new Person
    {
        ...
        CityId = city.Id,
        ...
    };

    // Proceed to save your Person object
}
```